# Unexpected Result when Overriding 'val'

Tags: scala, overriding

In Scala 2.10.4, Given the following class:

```
scala> class Foo { 
     |   val x = true
     |   val f = if (x) 100 else 200
     | }
defined class Foo
```

The following two examples make sense to me:

```
scala> new Foo {}.f
 res0: Int = 100

scala> new Foo { override val x = false}.f
res1: Int = 200
```

But, why doesn't this call return `100`?

```
scala> new Foo { override val x = true }.f
res2: Int = 200
```

Comment: Dude, http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because vals aren't initialized more than once, `x` is actually `null` (or `false` for a default `Boolean`) during the initialization of `Foo`, and then initialized in the anonymous class that is extending `Foo` in your example.

We can test it more easily with an `AnyRef`:

```
class Foo { 
    val x = ""
    val f = if (x == null) "x is null" else "not null"
}

scala> new Foo { override val x = "a" }.f
res10: String = x is null

scala> new Foo {}.f
res11: String = not null
```

There's a full explanation in the [Scala FAQ](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html). Excerpt:

> Naturally when a val is overridden, it is not initialized more than once. So though x2 in the above example is seemingly defined at every point, this is not the case: an overridden val will appear to be null during the construction of superclasses, as will an abstract val.

A simple way to avoid this would be to use a lazy val or def, if the val being referenced may be overridden.

Additionally, you can use the `-Xcheckinit` compiler flag to warn you about potential initialization errors like this.

Comment: So, it's not possible to **override** a `val` then? In your above example, `x` is *null*, rather than set to `"a"`. Makes me ask why a `val` should even be over-ridden - given the above behavior?

Comment: @KevinMeredith You can override a val, it's just that you have to be very careful about initialization problems when you do. Namely, when you override a val that another val in the super-class depends on. In the context of your problem, it can't be overridden and still function properly without making something lazy.

Comment: Yes, if you change `f` to be a `def` or `lazy`, then it will be called after initialization and work.

Comment: `It is inadvisable to use this flag outside of testing.` http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html